# Iterating through JSON.Parse() results in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am a rails newb but loving it....Anyway I have run into a problem and can't seem to find what I'm looking for as most things already asked are with an ActiveRecord object, etc and I'm actually using JSON.parse from a rest webservice.

I can't iterate through the object without errors or blank rows in my table (in the view). I know what I have in the view code is wrong but i've tried a lot of different things I've read

What should I do in the view or do I need to convert to a different data type before sending to a view? Any help you can give, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Controller Code:

```
class WidgetController < ApplicationController
  def index
    widget = Widget.new
    @widgets = widget.fetchAll
  end
end
```

Model Code:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
# class Widget
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'
  def fetchAll
    uri = URI.parse("https://example.com/widgets")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response = http.request(request)
    return JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

View Code:

```
<% @widgets.each do |widget| -%>
   <tr>
     <td><%= puts "#{widget['id']}" %></td>
     <td><%= widget[:name] %></td>
     <td><%= widget.description %></td>
   </tr>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: What does the JSON from https://example.com/widgets looks like? Is it an array? Detailed layout?

Comment: Thanks Franklin, I actually figured it out: `<%= widget['id'] %>` worked, I realized with the 'puts' it was printing out on the console, swore I tried that!

Comment: Yes, and I guess you come from PHP background. In Rails `puts` in template prints it in server log instead of on webpage.

Comment: Also, rails is a full fledged web animal.  As such, you don't need to require json or net/http--that's already done for you.

Comment: Just a small tip: You don't need to write `"#{widget['id']}"`, just `widget['id']` will work.

Comment: Do try and follow Rails naming conventions: `fetch_all` is preferred, variable and method names should be lower-case only. It's also a good idea to promote `require` statements to the very top of your file unless you have a very specific reason for deferring their loading.

Answer (score 0):

That url `"https://example.com/widgets"` returns a response containing an error.  In rails, the response object looks like this:

```
#<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true>
```

If you look closely, you can see a `404 Not Found` error in there.  You can output the response object like this:

```
...
...
response = http.request(request)
puts "*" * 20
p response
puts "-" * 20
```

then look in the window where you started your server:

```
...
...
Started GET "/users/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-18 20:57:16 -0700
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
********************
#<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true>
--------------------
...
...
```

Or, you can employ something with possibly friendlier output, like the `curl command` on the command line:

```
~$ curl -v "https://example.com/widgets"
*   Trying 93.184.216.34...
* Connected to example.com (93.184.216.34) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: www.example.org
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA

> GET /widgets HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2017 03:59:57 GMT
< Expires: Sun, 26 Feb 2017 03:59:57 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 
...
...
```

(`-v` stands for verbose, which outputs both the sent headers with the request as well as the received headers with the response.  Without the -v option the headers will be omitted in the output.)

The right facing `>` is the text of the request.  The left facing `<` is the text of the response.  Notice the 404 Not Found status in the first line of the response.